# How to loop insert data to database in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want insert data using loop to my database. I have view, name is **'form.php'**.

```
<!-- STEP 3 -->
<fieldset>
    <h2>Kebutuhan Khusus</h2><p>(bila ada)</p>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Calon Mahasiswa</label>
  <select name="keb[0][jns_kebutuhan]" class="form-control" id="cama">
    <option value="">--Jenis Kebutuhan--</option>
    <option value="Tuna Netra">Tuna Netra</option>
    <option value="Tuna Grahita">Tuna Grahita</option>
    <option value="Tuna Wicara">Tuna Wicara</option>
    <option value="Tuna Rungu">Tuna Rungu</option>
    <option value="Tuna Daksa">Tuna Daksa</option>
    <option value="Lainnya">Lainnya</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="keb[0][subjek]" value="Calon Mahasiswa">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Ayah</label>
  <select name="keb[1][jns_kebutuhan]" class="form-control" id="ayah">
    <option value="">--Jenis Kebutuhan--</option>
    <option value="Tuna Netra">Tuna Netra</option>
    <option value="Tuna Grahita">Tuna Grahita</option>
    <option value="Tuna Wicara">Tuna Wicara</option>
    <option value="Tuna Rungu">Tuna Rungu</option>
    <option value="Tuna Daksa">Tuna Daksa</option>
    <option value="Lainnya">Lainnya</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="keb[1][subjek]" value="Ayah">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Ibu</label>
  <select name="keb[2][jns_kebutuhan]" class="form-control" id="ibu">
    <option value="">--Jenis Kebutuhan--</option>
    <option value="Tuna Netra">Tuna Netra</option>
    <option value="Tuna Grahita">Tuna Grahita</option>
    <option value="Tuna Wicara">Tuna Wicara</option>
    <option value="Tuna Rungu">Tuna Rungu</option>
    <option value="Tuna Daksa">Tuna Daksa</option>
    <option value="Lainnya">Lainnya</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="keb[2][subjek]" value="Ibu">
</div>
```

And my controller '**Pascasarjana.php**'

```
foreach ($_POST['keb'] as $keb) {
    $this->m_pascasarjana->kebutuhan('tbl_kebutuhan',$keb);
  }
```

And my model is

```
function kebutuhan($table,$data) {
  $last_row = $this->db->select('id_pendaftar')->order_by('id_pendaftar',"desc")->limit(1)->get('tbl_datapribadi')->row()->id_pendaftar;
  $data['id_pendaftar'] = $last_row;
  $query = $this->db->insert($table,$data);
  return $this->db->insert_id();
} //END FUNCTION//
```

I try using my controller, If one of the forms is not filled data contains 0 in my database. I want if i not filled one of the forms, no data filled in the database. How to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function kebutuhan($table,$data) 
{
  $last_row = $this->db->select('id_pendaftar')->order_by('id_pendaftar',"desc")->limit(1)->get('tbl_datapribadi')->row()->id_pendaftar;
  if(!empty($data['jns_kebutuhan']))
  {
     $data['id_pendaftar'] = $last_row;
     $query = $this->db->insert($table,$data);
  }
  return $this->db->insert_id();
} //END FUNCTION//
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change Model.

```
 function kebutuhan($table,$data) {
      $last_row = $this->db->select('id_pendaftar')->order_by('id_pendaftar',"desc")->limit(1)->get('tbl_datapribadi')->row()->id_pendaftar;
      $data = $last_row->result_array();
      $query = $this->db->insert($table,$data);
     return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: What i can change in my model?

Comment: $data = $last_row->result_array();
      $query = $this->db->insert($table,$data);

Comment: hello $last row you cant get id number?